im trying to use pynput to press enter but its not registering, ive looked around quite a bit and i cant see anyone else having this problem
im writing a program that writes a program (my coding skill sucks dont worry about it) and when i run this line:
keyboard.press(Key.enter) it doesnt work at all (its also not returning any errors so im very confused)
ive also tried pyautogui.press('enter')and it does nothing
here is the full function, if you need additional info just ask
def creatingfile():
    #locating the folder
    folder = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'no seeing ahah\folder.png', confidence=0.9)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(folder)
    print("located folder")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()
    print("clicked the folder")

    #creating the file
    createfile = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'no seeing again aahaha\createfile.png', confidence=0.9)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(createfile)
    print("located create file button")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()
    print("created the file")

    #naming the file
    time.sleep(1.5)
    name = 'programwrittenbyaprogram.py'

    for char in name:
        pyautogui.press(char)
        print("letter typed")
        ts = random.uniform(0.05, 0.15)
        time.sleep(ts)
    print("finished naming the file") 
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("pressed enter")

    time.sleep(2)

creatingfile()

if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated :)

if you are working with the file structure on your own computer you should really look at os.mkdir() to create folders and then open() to write a file in the path of the newly created folder.
If you are trying to stick with this pyautogui vision creation - are you sure that the enter key can be pressed? is there a box that is selected and allows key input? (can you give insight into what you are trying to do and where)

im trying to create and name a file in vs code using the buttons and detecting them with locatecenteronscreen, but when its done and you need to press enter to finish naming the file it just doesnt do anything

How are you detecting the press of enter? By the way, whatever way you are testing the press of enter, you should also try it in a different way to see if that does anything. Open up a browser search bar, type something in, run the program, and see if pressing 'enter' on the program works. Also, try keyboard.press_and_release('enter').
